# javadoc for String[] args

Tags: javadoc, program-entry-point

I want to make good documentation for my program.
Function main receives parameters from command-line: LOGIN, PASSWORD etc(there are 9 parameters).

```
/**
* Command-line interface.   
* @param args LOGIN - login of user PASSWORD - password, row splitter - symbol after each row in text file
*/
public static void main(String[] args){

}
```

But for person who will read html-documentation it's will be not convenient to find decription for every parameter.
Is it the better way to make javadoc for each parameter(like @param login, @param password @param rowsplitter)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like Commons CLI, this make your life easier when documenting the expected input and also when eventually extending the functionality of your program.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Answer (score 4):

Addendum to user1681360's answer: Javadoc is intended for documentation targeted at *developers*, i.e. users of your classes and interfaces or people wanting to modify them. Documentation of commandline arguments is primarily interesting to the user of the *application* as a whole, so having it in the javadoc is suboptimal.

Commons CLI (or similar libs) allow you to properly document the argument in a way that it's both easy to read for someone reading your code and - more importantly - easy to read and access by the user of the application. Namely by

- Providing a `--help` parameter that describes all options in a format the user is familiar with
- Providing a `--help` parameter that always shows the *actual* set of supported parameters, without you having to actively maintain that documentation
- Ensuring that your parameter parsing roughly behaves in a way the user is familiar with (meaning you need less documentation)